# Preloading fonts doesn't work, at least not in google pagespeed. Can someone explain why?

Tags: html, preload

In google pagespeed insights there is a suggestion that I preload two fonts, one is a `woff2` and the other is `woff`. I use Autoptimize and WP Rocket as caching plugins.

I basically tried everything. Set the original path to the fonts in the preload tag, I created a new folder in the root with the fonts, I used cdn for preloading the fonts, I tried it `w/` and `w/o` the crossorigin attribute and nothing seems to help.

Sometimes, but only sometimes the problem seems to be resolved (according to pagespeed insights) and most of the times it's still there.

In the source code of the page you can see the additional tags in the header section, so I can't seem to understand what is going on here.

```
<html lang="de-DE">
<head>
<link rel=”preload” as="font" type="font/woff2" href=”/fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2″ crossorigin>
<link rel=”preload” as="font" type="font/woff" href=”/fonts/wpdatatablesicons-base.woff″ crossorigin>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

The page is to find [here](https://testinstallation.online/)

Comment: I'm getting a 400 error on the first call to load a font `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed%3A100&subset=latin&ver=5.2.4`. Is this expected? Might be mucking with things. I'm using Brave Version 0.70.122 Chromium: 78.0.3904.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Mac.

Comment: No it's not. I used an irregular font-weight attribute (100) somewhere. At least it looks like it. I'll try to find it now. Thanks very much for your contribution!

update: I found it, thanks again.